# Minimize a sum over permutations

Tags: optimization, summation, permutations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

A friend send me this exercise. I haven't be able to solve it since, except finding particular cases for $n=2$ or $n=3$. What would be your starting point ?

Can we find the optimal $\sigma$ ? And can we compute the value of the sum for such a $\sigma$ ?

$$\min_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{\sigma(i)}{i}\right\rfloor$$

Where $\mathfrak{S}_n$ denotes the permutations set.

Comment: Can you show your work for the small cases? Any hypothesis for what the minimum is, and when it is achieved?

Comment: I found 2 for $\sigma=(1,2)$ and 2 for $\sigma=(2,3)$